# Toggle the title of a UIButton when it is tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I want a UIButton when tapped to change its title to "Restart" and when tapped again to change its title to "Stop". This code I have changes the Button title to "Restart" but when I tap on the button again nothing happens.

```
-(IBAction)restartPressed{
    if (self.restart){
      [self.restart setTitle:"@Restart" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    else {
      [self.restart setTitle:"@Stop" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a global boolean variable:

```
var isButtonClicked = false

@IBAction func restartClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    isButtonClicked = !isButtonClicked
    restartButton.setTitle(isButtonClicked ? "Stop" : "Restart", for: .normal)
}
```

The code is in swift. You can convert it to objective C

Answer (score 5):

You need to set both times the state for `UIControlStateNormal`. `UIControlStateSelected` is a state, what is barley visible.

Declare a variable, what you update every time the button is being pressed.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isRestart;
```

Than set the title for the right state observing the above declared value.

```
 - (IBAction) restartPressed {
    self.isRestart = !self.isRestart;
    if (self.isRestart){
      [self.restart setTitle:@"Restart" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
      [self.restart setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }
}
```

Also, make sure the `restartPressed` function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Declare int i and int rem globally:

```html
@interface ViewController ()
{
    int i;
    int rem;
}
```

Then in your restart button Action add the below code:

```html
- (IBAction)restartPressed:(id)sender

{
    if((rem = i % 2 == 0))
    {
        [_restartBtn setTitle:@"restart"  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        i=i+1;
    }
    else
    {
        [_restartBtn setTitle:@"stop"  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        i=i+1;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

In ViewDidLoad

```
[btn setTitle:@"Restart" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[btn setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


- (IBAction) restartPressed:(UIButton *)btn {
    btn.selected = !btn.isSelected;
}
```